# How to clear UWP WebView cache?

Tags: windows, caching, webview, uwp

I am using WebView in my UWP application and I want to clear the cache while closing the app, is there a way? I know I can disable cache by adding headers into my HttpRequestMessage as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391437/universal-windows-10-webview-how-to-clear-disable-cache) link. However, I want to be able to clear the cache upon app exit.

I did try WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync() without any success. 
Once something is cached it normally remains throughout the app.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit : Adding code snippet

```
var webView = new WebView();  
webView.Navigate(new Uri("http://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache-test/"));  
await WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync(); //static method  
webView.Navigate(new Uri("http://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache-test/"));
```

I expect the static method to clear cache and when I navigate to same page again its cache should be cleared. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Could you please describe a scenario? What cache data you cannot clear from the universal app?

Comment: Do you have a code-sample to reproduce that ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync does not work for you?

Comment: @Konstantin Added a code snippet

Comment: I updated my answer -- your code actually works for me. If you want to refresh after "green image" - per site design you should click on the link inside page to reset it.

Answer (score 7):

In UWP (XAML) there is the [`ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.cleartemporarywebdataasync.aspx) method, that allows to webview's cache and IndexedDB data. And there is similar method for JavaScript in MSApp - [`clearTemporaryWebDataAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764996.aspx).

Here is code sample (based on your one) that works for me:

XAML:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <StackPanel>
         <WebView x:Name="webView" Width="800" Height="600"></WebView>
         <Button x:Name="refreshBtn" Content="Refresh" ></Button>
     </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

C#:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        refreshBtn.Tapped += RefreshBtn_Tapped;

        webView.Navigate(new Uri("http://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache-test/"));


    }

    private async void RefreshBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync();
        webView.Navigate(new Uri("http://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache-test/"));
    }
```

When I click refresh button, cache is cleared -- I see green image.

Comment: I am not able to clear the cache using this code sample of yours. I tried it on 3 different machines inlcuding a phone, I never saw the green image. Also, sometimes the app throws "Access Denied" exception on ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync call or does not return from the call at all.

Comment: I created just a new project with the code above. Can you publish full code of your sample application so that I could reproduce it? I suppose there might be some additional dependencies.

Comment: I created a new project as well with same code you have posted above. It still did not work for me. You did not add any capabilities or anything extra right?

Comment: Thanks. Adding this line work for me.   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync();

Answer (score 0):

There was no possibility to do it in 8.1 according
[Ten Things You Need to Know About WebView – An Update for Windows 8.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/04/03/ten-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview-an-update-for-windows-8-1/#AN7)

the closest method you can use now is [WebView.Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.refresh.aspx) that "reloads the file without forced cache validation by sending a "Pragma:no-cache" header to the server."
... or just clear cache in explorer