# prevent Javascript cacehing by appending timestamp or version

Tags: javascript, caching

I want to append a random number or a timestamp at the end of the javascript files(large number of js and css files) source path in so that every time the page reloads it should download a fresh copy.

for the list of js and css files, code below will not work for list of js,css files.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var randomh = Math.random();
            var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
            var d = document.createElement("script");
            d.src = e.src+"?x=" + randomh + "";
            d.type = "text/javascript";
            d.async = true;
            d.defer = true;
            e.parentNode.insertBefore(d, e);
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have access to anything like PHP where you can append a rand() at the end. Or anything like RequireJS or AngularJS - The only other option I see is to make an array of file names and loop through on page load but you will have problems with CSS and JavaScript and dom rendering

Comment: i am using AngularJs, there is grunt plugin called grunt-cache-control, it does the same, append version number but the issue here is it appends by looking script and link tags in index.html(Angularjs), i am loading my controllers using lazy load to load files, how do i add versions in the js files in config.lazyload

Comment: Paste your full code including the lazyload section. You can just append something like `var Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1);`