# Can you disable a service worker before the page loads?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My team and I have a project that was originally built as a PWA, but have since decided to scrap that idea as we realized it would need to change much more frequently than originally intended. However, the service worker is already live, as well as a newly redesigned landing page for the website. Despite all our efforts to clear the PWA caching, our clients are still reporting that they are receiving the old cached version of the website.

Currently, we have the service worker set up to delete all caches upon install (and whenever anything at all happens as a precaution), as well as some JavaScript to unregister the service worker when the new page *actually* loads. However, the problem is that none of this runs until the user makes a request to the website, and at that point the browser is already loading the cached content. Is it possible to clear this cache *and* prevent the browser from loading any content that was already cached?

**Current service-worker.js**

```
// Caching
var cacheCore = 'mkeSculptCore-0330121058';
var cacheAssets = 'mkeSculptAssets-0330121058';

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    self.skipWaiting();

    caches.keys().then(function (names) {
        for (let name of names)
            caches.delete(name);
    });
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    caches.keys().then(function (names) {
        for (let name of names)
            caches.delete(name);
    });
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    caches.keys().then(function (names) {
        for (let name of names)
            caches.delete(name);
    });
});
```

**Script in index.html**

```
(function () {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
            //returns installed service workers
            if (registrations.length) {
                for (let registration of registrations) {
                    registration.unregister();
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

So far, I've read a few other similar StackOverflow answers, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986976/how-can-i-remove-a-buggy-service-worker-or-implement-a-kill-switch), but they tend to rely on users manually doing something to fetch the new content, ie. via a hard reload or disabling the service worker manually through the browser settings. However, in my case, we cannot rely on manual user actions.

Comment: Tricky question, what about deploying a new html page with some js code that unregisters the service-worker and tell your customers to go to this url. 

Or, if you have some 'network-first' html/js ressources you can put the  unregister code there.

Comment: @StefChäser Thanks for the feedback. I should clarify; this is a public informational website, so we have some "pedestrian users" that might just check in occasionally for updates that may have been posted regarding the event. Therefore, we really have very little control over manual user actions, including directing them to a specific URL. I know this doesn't sound like the use case for PWAs/Service Workers, but the homepage was originally intended to be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is to add a timestamp at end of the file(js, css) name so each time when it is making a request, the cache key is not available in the service worker and thus it tends to get a new version of the file at each load.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scipt1.js?t=05042018121212"/>
```

For appending a new timestamp dynamically in the file name, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11467981/7954042)

But this may not be reliable if HTML itself is cached.

Comment: Unfortunately, the HTML is my biggest problem here :/

Answer (score 0):

add this before to "update" all contents:

```
$.each(['index.html','file1.js','file2.js','file3.js'],function(index,file) {
      $.get(file+'?t='+new Date().getTime(), function(){});
});
location.reload(true);
```

for the ServiceWorker to stop all windows using it must be closed.
If it's a webapp you can use window.close();

This code just loads a fresh version of the files in the list.
If there are any internal caches they will be all updated.